# Getting Images Stored on a Web Site Hosted in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a basic web site hosted in Windows Azure. This is a web site running under SHARED mode. It allows users to upload a couple of photos. Currently, users can successfully upload photos. The uploaded photos get stored in a directory thats created dynamically based on the username.

I need to download these photos for backup purposes. My question is, how do I get them? Its not like I can login to the machine and just grab the directory structure and zip it up.

What options do I have here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all data which is stored in Windows Azure Web Sites through FTP (more info: [Windows Azure Website: Uploading/Downloading files over FTP and collecting Diagnostics logs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/19/windows-azure-website-uploading-downloading-files-over-ftp-and-collecting-diagnostics-logs.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to upload the photos to [Azure Blob Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/). They will be securely stored in the cloud and you will have access to them any time you need. Also if anything happen on your server, you will be able to fetch the photos from the blob service.

You will not have to even download user photos for backup if they are stored in the blob.